# validate Method is not Working in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

iam new to backbone.js. i was trying validate method to validate age in my sample code by still iam able to Set the age to Negative number can you please help me out. I dont knew where iam getting Wrong. Here my code,

```
var Human = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'myName',
        age: 26
    },
    validate: function (attrs) {
        if(attrs.age < 0){        
            return "please enter a valide age";
        }
    }});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass {validate:true} param to set method e.g.

```
Human.set('age', -25, {validate:true});
```